# Change boolean to false via button onclick method located in navigation bar

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to change the following variable to false  using the onclick method of a button in my shared navbar.

**Variable**

```
public static bool LoginStatus { get; set; } = true;
```

What I have so far which does not work:

**Html button**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=@Apex_Leaderboard_Website.Models.LoginViewModel.LoginStatus = false>Log Out</button>
```

I have tried a form but with the button in the shared navbar it makes it difficult to submit it to the appropriate handler.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `asp:Button` because you want to modify a C# class property. then you can OnClick event on it so that you will be able to call a backend(code-behind) method and in that method, you can set the `enter code here` to `false`.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.8) is the reference for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use posting a form or use js.

```
<form method="post" asp-route-LoginStatus=false>
    <input type="submit" value="Log Out" />
</form>
```

js:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="passData()">Log Out</button>

function passData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "xxx",
                data: { LoginStatus: false },
                success: function(data) {
                   
                }
            });

        }
```

action:

```
public ActionResult xxx(bool LoginStatus)
{
    ....
}
```